# Sharing my purchased movies on friends Apple TV

Tags: itunes

How do I share my purchased movies on Apple TV? I have purchased movies on my computer and would like to share with my grandchildren on Apple TV.  How do I do it?

Answer (score 1):

I would set up [family sharing](http://www.apple.com/icloud/family-sharing/). My wife and I share an account for all our apple purchases and it works great. You can have up to 6 people in the family group.

I would check if your son/daughter already have sharing set up and if so would ask them to add you.

I am making the assumption that you purchased your movies via iTunes and that your computer in a Mac.

Comment: Family sharing is definitely the best and easiest way to do this, assuming as you said the purchases were made from the iTunes Store. However, the OP doesn't need to have a Mac for this to work. As long as they have *either* a Mac or iPhone or iPad or iPod running iOS 8 or above.

Comment: You are of course correct about either Mac, iPhone or iPad.